# how can we decide or find upper and lower bound in binary search questions of competitive programming?

Tags: binary-search

I recently saw the topcoder binary search tutorial in which i understand where we can apply binary search but while solving questions or in topcoder tutorial i didn't understood that how we can decide our lower and upper bound values and on what basis.

Answer (score 0):

The search space has a lower and upper limit. After each query we either raise the lower bound or decrease the upper bound.

Let's say you are trying to guess somebody's number, in the range 0 to 100.
If you guess 50, in the middle, in binary search, and the person says 50 is too high, then you can decrease your upper bound to 50 and the search space becomes 0 to 50 instead.

There must be an evaluation function to determine whether a guess is too "high" or "low", and if the result is too "high", the upper bound is lowered, while if it is too "low", the lower bound is increased.

It may not be as straightforward as a number range, it could be indexes of a sorted array, or numbers put into evaluation functions to determine the difference. The lower bound is the smallest possible guess which could still be correct while the upper bound is the highest possible guess which could still be correct.

Each time, we remove all numbers we know are wrong for sure from the search space.